# Append to 'IT' description name in jasmine

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor

I've been trying to alter my 'IT' descriptions on runtime, knowing protractor is Async, I still feel I'm missing something.

```
describe('Describe something', function() {
    var testParams = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
    var testVar;
    beforeEach( function() {
        // ...
        testVar = "Eyooo";
    });

for (var i = 0; i < testParams.length; i++) {
  (function (testSpec) {
    // ...

    it('should do something '+testVar , function () {
    //...
      console.log(testVar);

    });

    // ...
  })(testParams[i]);

};
```

});

its this part I've been having trouble with

```
it('should do something '+testVar , function () {
```

Knowing that the cases are being handled Async, I've been having a tough time trying to figure out WHEN the 'it' description is loaded.

When I rune the above this is my output

```
Describe something                                                                                                                                              
√ should do something undefined                                                                                                                               
Eyooo                                                                                                                                                             
√ should do something undefined                                                                                                                               
Eyooo
```

So the result was kinda obvious, yet I've been having a tough time wrapping my head around this. I suppose this goes against the industry standard, but it would really help my case.

I also tried something like this..

```
it('should do something', function() {    
    testVar = "Eyooo";
});

it('should do something '+testVar, function () {
    //...
    console.log(testVar);     
});
```

to no avail

Any input is welcome!

Comment: @Kishan Patal I should not have put 'Any' input is welcome, constructive input is welcome tho.

Answer (score 1):

That was a great question. Had to brainstorm a lot!

You are spot on reg the root cause the error. It behaves async
And the solution I see to dynamically construct description of `"IT"` blocks is to the assign the name not through `BeforeEach()` but calling a custom function to do so

Please check the same example that you quoted but modified to construct IT description

```
describe('Describe something', function() {
    var testParams = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
    var testVar;
    for (var i = 0; i < testParams.length; i++) {
        (function (testSpec) {
            // ...

            it(getName(), function () {
                //...
                console.log(testVar);

            });

            // ...
        })(testParams[i]);

    };
    function getName(){
        testVar = "Eyooo";
        return 'should do something '+testVar
    }
});
```

The other example, instead of writing the logic of building the description in another IT block, build it in another custom function and call it

```
describe('Describe something', function() {
    var testVar
    it(getName(), function () {
        //...
        console.log(testVar);
    });
    function getName(){
        testVar = "Eyooo";
        return 'should do something '+testVar
    }
});
```

Comment: any updates on this.. Interested to know if this worked for you

Comment: Back from hollidays, Sorry !

But it did not work for me, I can get a static string printed in the line, but I can not dynamicly set and get the data based on the test.

I will take a look tonight and see if I can reproduce it.